# No carbonation in my Ginger Brew

Tags: carbonation

I added my ginger bug to my Ginger Brew. It's now been 5 days with no visible signs of carbonation. Should I Add more ginger bug to my Brew?

Comment: The Ginger Brew is in bottles right?  Or a Fermenter?   What did you put in your Brew?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you bottled the bug + ginger sugar-water - It's best to wait.  At least for 2 weeks, then re-evaluate.

Are the bottles warm ?  More than 15C / 59F ?   Ale yeast (and bread making yeast) will go dormant if it's too cold.

It could be there's only a small amount of yeast in each bottle, and it's taking time to establish itself.  It *may* help to gently agitate the bottles to rouse the yeast.